# Run a batch file after visual studio installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment

Am having a windows service exe that starts xxx.exe. After i created a setup file, I cant able to launch the service automatically

So I wrote a batch file having commands ( service.exe -i ).

Can anyone tell me how to run a .bat file after installation through vs2008 setup and deployment ?

Comment: What does the batch file do?  Does it install and start the service?

Comment: yes it should install and start the service by sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The problem  you are facing is that Visual Studio Deployment Projects don't expose much of the underlying Windows Installer capabilities.  It was for this and many other reasons that Microsoft killed this project type in Visual Studio 2012.

This feature gap is forcing you to reinvent the wheel with a less robust design.  From an MSI perspective it's an out of process anti-pattern.

If it was me, I'd use WiX and IsWiX ( both found on CodePlex ) to create this MSI.  A short (10 minute) video can be seen over on my blog on how to create a windows service, create an installer for it, check it all into TFS and get it to build and finally test on a virtual machine.  From zero to test ready is 10 minutes.

[IsWiX 2.0.13013.4 Released](http://blog.iswix.com/2013/01/iswix-20130134-released.html)